# Creating a read more link for blog.

Tags: ee2, entries, vimeo

I am working on a site that has a main entry but as I post new entries, it pushes existing content down into summarized items the user can click on for more. I want to have a little summary so the user can read a quick outline of what is being discussed or viewed without having to click on it. I would like to have the typical "Read More" link, however I am not exactly sure how to set that up or code it.

I came across this article while I was searching for possible solutions.

http://colly.com/comments/more-more-more-links-in-expression-engine/

However, I see that it was posted in 2006 so I was curious if this was what I was looking for and secondly if this is still the method used today. I currently have my entries set up with a title, a vimeo link and also a text entry about what the video is going to cover. Thanks for any help, as always it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two primary options here.

The first, which I'd recommend, is to have a dedicated "Summary" field in your channel. This way the summary can be specifically-crafted as a *summary*, which is far more useful to your readers, rather than just whatever the first X-number of words of your entry happens to be. Then, display it with a link to your full entry:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="10"}
    <h2><a href="{title_permalink="blog/entry"}">{title}</a></h2>
    {blog_summary}
    <p><a href="{title_permalink="blog/entry"}">Read more ...</a></p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

(Where **blog/entry** is your single entry template, in which you display all your fields for a single entry.)

Your other, lazier option is to use a plugin on your content field, like [Hacksaw](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hacksaw), which truncates your content into a summary:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="10"}
    <h2><a href="{title_permalink="blog/entry"}">{title}</a></h2>
    {exp:eehive_hacksaw words="50" append="..."}
        {blog_content}
    {/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
    <p><a href="{title_permalink="blog/entry"}">Read more ...</a></p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Either one will get the job done for you.

Comment: I can confirm that either of Derek's suggestions will work. In my hobby EE site (a blog with Read More links) I have the body content broken down into several fields: an intro, body, and extended body. I display the intro paragraph on "listings" pages, like all entries in a certain month or all entries in a certain category. On my index page, I have the word_limiter plugin to truncate the intro field to 6o words, then it adds the final ellipsis. So I'm using both solutions, but in different places and for different effects.

Comment: I had a couple issues but it was all on my end. Your solution works exactly the way I was hoping. Thank you so much for your help!